# Formated column in openpyxls gets hidden. Is this a bug or a feature?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using the below code to format a file that was created using the latest version of MS Excel.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Fill

wb=load_workbook("test.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
col = ws.column_dimensions['B']
col.font = Font(bold=True)
wb.save("styled.xlsx")
```

When I run this code, column B which should be formated to bold text, instead gets hidden. This also applies for other styles that I tried. I also tried other columns and other excel files which were generated by pandas using the xlswriter engine.

My last resort was to try various versions of openpyxl, including the latest beta. They all behave in the same way for the above code.

So my question is, am I missing anything? All I want to do is format a column's content to bold text column wise (not cell wise).

Comment: Please read the documentation on this carefully: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#applying-styles

Comment: You are right and I indeed saw this earlier "Styles can also applied to columns and rows but note that this applies only to cells created (in Excel) after the file is closed." But what exactly does it mean? The xlsx in questions needs cells that were created in excel explicitly? What does "after the file is closed" mean? I need to open it, to apply styles using openpyxls, don't I?

Comment: It means that openpyxl annotates the file accordingly but itself ignores row and column styles.

Comment: But that's what I am doing on the above example. Open the workbook and annotate/add styles. Or what does annotate mean? Sorry for not catching up on this so quickly... ;)

Comment: You're annotating something that Excel cares about but openpyxl doesn't. The next time you add a cell to column B it will be bold but you might want to set the width first.

Comment: I am getting there... but find it super confusing at the moment. thanks anyhow for clarifying.